# Qt eventFilter for CTRL+TAB shortcut is processed further even when true is returned

Tags: c++, qt, mdi

I'm trying to override the <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> behaviour of `QMdiArea` by installing an `eventFilter` on the area.

The implementation I'm using to test ignoring the event is as follow:

```
bool 
MyEventFilterClass::eventFilter(QObject * watched, QEvent * e)
{
  if (e->type() == QEvent::KeyPress || e->type() == QEvent::KeyRelease ||
      e->type() == QEvent::Shortcut || e->type() == QEvent::ShortcutOverride)
  {
    // Ignore all keyboard and shortcut events
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I'd think that ignoring all key- and shortcut-events would block <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> from being handled by the `QMdiArea`, but this is not correct. Even when returning true for all event, <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> still works fine although the next active window is not highlighted as it is normally.

Note that I'll implement my own behaviour once I'm able to block the standard behaviour.

How do I block <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> from being processed?

Comment: Are you sure you are entering that if block? (i.e. if you put a debug print statement before `return true;`, do you see it printed?)

Comment: @Mat: yes, it's entering the block. And as stated, returning true for any event doesn't block the CTRL+TAB behaviour either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QMdiArea` is already using an event filter to catch <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd>, so you have to create a derived class of `QMdiArea` and redefine its `eventFilter` function.

And since there is a lot of other things in `QMdiArea::eventFilter`, don't forget to call it back for the events you don't want to block or handle.